# Select option echo only coming weekdays php

Tags: php, html, date

I have the below code which displays only weekdays in php.

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++): ?>
<label ><?php echo date('l',strtotime("+$i Weekday")); ?>,</label>
<label ><?php echo date('M d', strtotime("+$i Weekday")); ?></label>
<br>   
<?php endfor; ?>
```

The code displays

```
Thursday, Sep 17 
Friday, Sep 18 
Monday, Sep 21 
Tuesday, Sep 22 
Wednesday, Sep 23
```

My goal is to display the weekdays in the below format;

```
Today --- How can I achieve this
Tomorrow --- How can I achieve this
Monday, Sep 21
Tuesday, Sep 22
Wednesday, Sep 23
```

I will like to use it in a `<select>` html tag and display the dates as options.
Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: if you want `Monday, Sep 21`, why are you using `d-M-Y` as your format string. Don't tell the computer you want apples and complain they're not oranges.

Comment: Edited my question :)

Comment: Using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$today = date('c');
$tomorrow = date('c', strtotime('+1 day'));

for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++){ ?>
<label><?php 
    if(date('c',strtotime("+$i day")) == $today){
        echo "Today";
    } elseif(date('c',strtotime("+$i days")) == $tomorrow){
        echo "Tomorrow";
    } else {
        echo date('l',strtotime("+$i day"));
        echo ", </label><label>";
        echo date('M d', strtotime("+$i day"));
    }
    ?></label>
<br>   
<?php } ?>
```

Output :

[image: Output]

**EDIT :** Don't show Saturday and Sunday :

```
<?php
$today = date('c');
$tomorrow = date('c', strtotime('+1 day'));

for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++){ 
    if(date('l',strtotime("+$i day")) != "Saturday" && date('l',strtotime("+$i day")) != "Sunday"){
        echo "<label>";
        if(date('c',strtotime("+$i day")) == $today){
            echo "Today";
        } elseif(date('c',strtotime("+$i days")) == $tomorrow){
            echo "Tomorrow";
        } else {
            echo date('l',strtotime("+$i day"));
            echo ", </label><label>";
            echo date('M d', strtotime("+$i day"));
        }
        echo "</label><br>";
    }
 }

?>
```

Output :

[image: Output]

Comment: Where did you set `$today` and `$tomorrow` var values? Your code seems incomplete

Comment: Way to go! Now it's an almost plain copy of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014999/how-to-make-a-check-if-this-timestamp-is-today-tomorrow-or-the-day-after-tomorro), stating that the question should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: I set `$today` and `$tomorrow` in my answer but oddly Stack Overflow didn't displayed it. However, I fixed it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work on the weekends. I get the below;

`Monday, Sep 28 
Monday, Sep 28 
Tuesday, Sep 29 
Wednesday, Sep 30 
Thursday, Oct 01`

Comment: Is there a way I can skip weekends and not show them as today and tomorrow. So just show from Monday etc and then on Monday we go back to using Today and tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code so there's no Saturday and Sunday days anymore.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated!